# Can someone who has tried to run Xcode 14.1 on a 2014 mac mini verify that they were they able to successfully develop an app using this setup

Tags: xcode, mac-mini, monterey, development, xcode-simulator

My brother wants to develop an iPhone app.  I have over 25 years of programming experience, but not for the iOS/Apple ecosystem.  In any case I decided to help him out, but I don't personally own any mac hardware.

I am trying to find the cheapest path to be able to develop an iPhone app.   Doing a little research reveals...

- "starting April 2023, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 14.1 and the iOS 16.1 SDK." [[1]](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/)
- Xcode only (legally) runs on mac hardware (so I need to get hardware somehow).
- Xcode 14.1 requires macOS Monterey 12.5 or newer [[2]](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)
- The oldest/cheapest mac that will run macOs Monterey is the Mac Mini from late 2014 [[3]](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212551)
- These would be part numbers MGEM2xx/A, MGEN2xx/A, MGEQ2xx/A [[4]](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201894)
- These model numbers are currently selling for like $100~$300 refurbished on eBay.

I think (on paper at least) that I have verified that I can run Xcode 14.1 on a 2014 mac mini.

So here is the main question.

**Can someone who has tried to run Xcode 14.1 on a 2014 mac mini verify that they were they able to successfully develop an app using this configuration.**

For context, let's assume I want to run the iOS simulator for test and debug.  I will use swift as the programming language.

Also assume that the app I am developing is not very resource intensive (no 3D or 2D animations or physics).  It will be a simple adventure story type game.  The user is first shown a static background image (JPEG), some text, and a menu.  The menu choice gets them to a new state, with a new image, text and menu options.  That continues until they reach the end of the story.

Answer (score 2):

The 2014 Mini comes with a range of different CPUs: from 1.4GHz i5 to a 3Ghz i7. However, all of them have only 2 cores. So they are quite weak (and 8 years' old). They certainly would not be 'unusable'; but they are at least 'not well suited' to development work. RAM will also be a factor.

Also, they don't have USB-C or TB3. Monterey is that last OS that they can run, so you're already 1 year behind current; if Apple changes the requirements in the future, you've got no way of meeting them.

It might be the cheapest way into the Apple eco-system, but not the most cost-effective, and you'd probably have to buy something else in a year or two. 'Buy cheap, pay twice', as my grandmother said.

I would suggest trying to find a secondhand 2018 Mini instead, which comes in 4-core i3 and 6-core i5 and i7 models. Apple still sells this model, but (secondhand) prices of the Intel models have fallen, as demand for the new Apple Silicon CPUs increases.

The 2018 Mini is a solid performer, which should last you a long time. I have the i5, and I use it for small Xcode projects with no problem.

Alternatively, it is thought that Apple will release an "M2" Mini early next year; at which point there may be a rush of secondhand M1 Minis onto the market. That would be your best option, if you can wait a bit (and maybe save a bit more cash).

Comment: Also, the minimal Xcode requirement will for sure raise again in 2024, so getting hardware from 2014 now means that new hardware will be required a year later.